# How to Broadcast from Android to other Java class?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

Is there any possibility to send a BroadcastMessage in Android from a "normal" Java class?

I tried it like this:

```
private void sendBroadcastMessage(String intentFilterName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentFilterName);
    intent.putExtra("response", response);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

but an error appears in the last line which says

> The method sendBroadcast(Intent) is undefined for the type Webserver_Connection

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You must send a broadcast from a context. Why you need to send broadcast from a java class which has no context !!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send a broadcast to other apps, or to the OS, you need to use `sendBroadcast()` on `Context`. Either pass in a `Context` to `sendBroadcastMessage()` or have `Webserver_Connection` hold a `Context`, being mindful of possible memory leaks.

If you are trying to communicate *within* your app, switch to [using `LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). That too will need a `Context`, to create your `LocalBroadcastManager` instance. However, it will improve performance and security. Or, switch from broadcasts entirely and use another in-process event bus implementation, such as greenrobot's EventBus or Square's Otto, neither of which need a `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
private void sendBroadcastMessage(Context context, String intentFilterName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentFilterName);
    intent.putExtra("response", response);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

However, you might consider:

```
private void sendBroadcastMessage(WeakReference<Context> weakContext, String intentFilterName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentFilterName);
    intent.putExtra("response", response);
    weakContext.get().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

If you store the context locally, otherwise your object may retain a reference to `Context` that it should not (resulting in a memory leak)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your java class is B.

```
class B {
    Context context;
    public B(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      sendBroadCast(context);
    }
    public void sendBroadCast(Context context){
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
      context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

You need to do something like this. 
sendBroadCast is a function of context. If you need to send broadcast only in app then you should use local broadcast